# Weight of edges is not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, directed-graph

I try to make graph like this using `networkx`:
[image]

When I try to draw edges weight, weight of edge 1->2 (which is 2) is not showing in my graph.

How can I fix this?

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

DGraph = nx.DiGraph()

vertex_list = [0,1,2,3,4]
edges_list = [(0,4,2),(0,2,3),(0,1,5),
(1,2,2),(1,3,6),
(2,1,1),(2,3,2),
(4,3,4),(4,2,10),(4,1,6),
]

DGraph.add_nodes_from(vertex_list)
DGraph.add_weighted_edges_from(edges_list)

DGraph._node[0]['pos'] = (0,8)
DGraph._node[1]['pos'] = (4,2)
DGraph._node[2]['pos'] = (2,-4)
DGraph._node[3]['pos'] = (-2,-4)
DGraph._node[4]['pos'] = (-4,2)

node_pos=nx.get_node_attributes(DGraph,'pos')
arc_weight=nx.get_edge_attributes(DGraph,'weight')

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(DGraph , pos=node_pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(DGraph , pos=node_pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(DGraph , node_pos,connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.05')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(DGraph , node_pos , arc_weight)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a well-asked first question. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Your code is fine. You are running into a limitation of networkx, which does not keep track of the arc of the edge when labelling edges. Instead, it places edge labels on a straight line between the two nodes; by default, it chooses the center of that straight line. This has two consequences for your plot:

1. the edge labels are slightly offset w.r.t. your edge paths, and
2. labels on bi-directional edges are plotted on top of each other.

There is no solution for the first issue; however, you can work around the second issue by specifying the argument `label_pos` to anything other than 0.5.
For example, changing your code to

```
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(DGraph, pos=node_pos, edge_labels=arc_weight, label_pos=0.33)
```

yields the following plot:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, it's exactly what ı wanna find on the internet